# Changing Text of CardsUI views

Tags: java, android, json, textview

So im using this awesome Cards library ([CardsUI](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android)) and trying to figure out how to insert my own text into these views grammatically. Im my main activity im parsing JSON data, now i want to use data from the JSON and insert the text into the Cards. Here is some code i have so far.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_enlighten);

      // the id title is referencing the title in my card layout below
    system_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    system_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.system_name);

    CardUI mCardView = (CardUI) findViewById(R.id.cardUI1);
    mCardView.setSwipeable(false);

    // add AndroidViews Cards
    mCardView.addCard(new MyCard("Get the CardsUI view"));
    mCardView.addCardToLastStack(new MyCard("for Android at"));
    MyCard androidViewsCard = new MyCard("www.androidviews.net");

    mCardView.addCardToLastStack(androidViewsCard);      
    // draw cards
    mCardView.refresh();

            // Here is my JSON Parsing activity.
            new ProgressTask(WelcomeYou.this).execute();        
      }
```

#### My Card Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/CardTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="title" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/stroke" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_cardbank"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        style="@style/CardText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="description" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Im simply trying to put text into the here `mCardView.addCard(new MyCard("PUT JSON STRING HERE"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was posted a while ago, but I'm just now using the CardUI and I've got it to work.  I don't know what R.id.activity_hello_enlighten contains, but if you look at the example provided with their source, the layout from your activity should be using a CardUI component.

Code from the example layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.fima.cardsui.views.CardUI
    android:id="@+id/cardsview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Otherwise there's nothing actually doing your card rendering to the screen.

Once you do this, get a pointer to the CardUI referenced by your layout (in the example code it's called cardsview) with the following code:

```
mCardView = (CardUI) findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
```

After that, it's as simple as adding a new card like this:

```
mCardView.addCardToLastStack(new MyCard("Your card's text!"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, eventually i figured it out basically exactly how you provided, Thanks for the code, i'll accept the answer.